# Generate Class.vb File Programmatically

Tags: sql, vb.net, class, builder

I want to create a class builder which will get the tables from the specified database and build my [className].vb file - at the push of a button!

For example:

```
Dim strBuilder As New StringBuilder

strBuilder.Append("Public class clsExample" & vbCrLf)

'Create variables
strBuilder.Append("Private _ID As String")
strBuilder.Append(vbCrLf)

'Create properties
strBuilder.Append("Public Property _ID() As Integer" & vbCrLf)
strBuilder.Append("Get" & vbCrLf)
strBuilder.Append("return _ID" & vbCrLf)
strBuilder.Append("end Get" & vbCrLf)
strBuilder.Append("Set(ByVal Value As Integer)" & vbCrLf)
strBuilder.Append("_ID = Value" & vbCrLf)
strBuilder.Append("End Set" & vbCrLf)
strBuilder.Append("End Property " & vbCrLf)
strBuilder.Append(vbCrLf)
strBuilder.Append(vbCrLf & "End Class")

Console.Write(strBuilder.ToString())
```

To get this result in the clsExample.vb file that was created using the previous code

```
Public Class clsExample
        Private _ID As String
        Public Property _ID() As Integer
            Get
                Return _ID
            End Get
            Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
                _ID = Value
            End Set
        End Property


    End Class
```

I'm not sure how to go about telling the program to create the [className].vb file and include my strBuilder as code in the file. Hope this makes sense...

Comment: It's probably overkill for your current need, but you should look at the [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx).

Comment: @MarkHurd Thanks, I looked into that previously. You're right it was overkill but still nice to know about it. I ended up building my class generator and it works great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing what you're asking here, but are you looking for something like this:

`IO.File.WriteAllText("className.vb",  strBuilder.ToString())`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx

Comment: That's it!!! thank you! It worked, but can you explain why the file is created in the directory i specified (where the mainForm.vb and all other files are located) yet I cannot see it in my project solution explorer?

Comment: I was able to click on "Include in project" for it to be visible. Is there a way to do that programmatically?

Comment: @Alex: Not sure on that, but I suspect its possible. BTW, "Include in Project" does allow you to do several files at once.

Comment: thanks, i'm looking into that right now on how to do it programmatically. Once that's done - i'll work on the script during my work week.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your approach :) But if you want any dynamic creation you need to connect the database and read all necessary shema informations.

I used this project http://sqldoc.codeplex.com/ once to read all data from a table to create some code out of it.
This maybe a good start for you.
This project creates a documentation, but you can even read all the data information and do something else with it (e.g. create a class that write source code in a text file => your class.vb).

Comment: Yes basically that's what I want to do. My question now contains a more elaborate example :)